# Make overlay fixed-like, but the content container scrollable

Tags: css, overlay

My code creates an overlay where it blocks up the page with black, and there's a form inside of inner container. When it's active, it blocks the page, but the overlay is absolute and stretches only the window width and height 100%, when I scroll down, the overlay is not  stretching.

When I make it fixed, it stays in one place, but the content of it is not scrollable.

How to make it like fixed, but also scrollable?

```
.quote_overlay, .email_overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(img/overlay_bg.png);
}

.quote_container, .email_container {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you just do make your parent overlay fixed and apply `.quote_container, .email_container { overflow-y: auto; }`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It won't overflow at all, bottom part of inner element is always cut off.

Comment: Can you craft a fiddle/plunker demonstrating the issue? No need for the background image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate your overlay element and the email container.
So to do this.

Your HTML:

```
<div class="email_container"></div>
<div class="email_overlay"></div>
```

Then on your css:

```
.email_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(img/overlay_bg.png);
  z-index: 1;
}

.email_container {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 2;
```

}

Comment: Oh, not bad. This might just do. Thanks.